# Keras simple RNN implementation

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I found problems when trying to compile a network with one recurrent layer. It seems there is some issue with the dimensionality of the first layer and thus my understanding of how RNN layers work in Keras.

My code sample is:

```
model.add(Dense(8,
                input_dim = 2,
                activation = "tanh",
                use_bias = False))
model.add(SimpleRNN(2,
                    activation = "tanh",
                    use_bias = False))
model.add(Dense(1,
                activation = "tanh",
                use_bias = False))
```

The error is

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer simple_rnn_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2
```

This error is returned regardless of `input_dim` value. What am I missing ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That message means: the input going into the rnn has 2 dimensions, but an rnn layer expects 3 dimensions.

For an RNN layer, you need inputs shaped like `(BatchSize, TimeSteps, FeaturesPerStep)`. These are the 3 dimensions expected.

A `Dense` layer (in keras 2) can work with either 2 or 3 dimensions. We can see that you're working with 2 because you passed an `input_dim` instead of passing an `input_shape=(Steps,Features)`.

There are many possible ways to solve this, but the most meaningful and logical would be a case where your input data is a sequence with time steps.

**Solution 1 - Your training data is a sequence:**

If your training data is a sequence, you shape it like `(NumberOfSamples, TimeSteps, Features)` and pass it to your model. Make sure you use `input_shape=(TimeSteps,Features)` in the first layer instead of using `input_dim`.

**Solution 2 - You reshape the output of the first dense layer so it has the additional dimension:**

```
model.add(Reshape((TimeSteps,Features)))
```

Make sure that the product `TimeSteps*Features` is equal to `8`, the output of your first dense layer.

Comment: Awesome, thank you, one additional question. First solution is working perfectly, but what If I want to have infinite time steps (theoretical question, I know, infinite time steps is foolish)? Then, I must use your second solution with reshaping output from first layer. But, I did simple test with memoizing sequences of XOR, and when I shuffled output, network failed to react to it as I expected. Better said, it was returning same outputs as before shuffle. How exactly reshaping affect working of recurrent layer (when compared with first solution)?

Comment: Reshaping just takes the data (any data), which is nothing more than a straight sequence of numbers divided in segments. Suppose you have 300 elements. When you reshape them like (30,10,1), you just separated these 300 elements in a different way. So, if you're reshaping for sequence purposes, you must have an idea of what you want to achieve and what is the format of your data, so you can reshape it in a significant way.

Comment: For your infinite sequence, you should probably work with an input of only 1 sample `(BatchSize=1, TimeSteps, Features)`, and mark your recurrent layers with `stateful=True`. This means that the layers will maintain their memory, and the next batch will be seen as continuing the previous batch in one single sequence. In this case, you must "erase the memory" (called "reset states") manually, when you decide that one sequence ended and you will start feeding another sequence.

Comment: Daniel Möller Thank you.