# Keras implementation for RNN

Tags: lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have coded LSTM as below. Now I would like to compare the performance of the RNN and LSTM. Actually, I know LSTM is a type of RNN. But how can I take the results from RNN on Keras? I could not find a proper RNN code example on Keras.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(15, input_shape=(max_fixation_length, feature_size,), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
# Compile model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])enter code here
```

Also, I have read this link [Keras simple RNN implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46256257/keras-simple-rnn-implementation) . However, I could not run it. Because Keras has given this error "undefined name 'SimpleRNN'"

Answer (score 2):

I understand that the fundamental problem that you are facing is "how to train RNNs (LSTM is a kind of RNN afterall) using Keras". I would point you to [this excellent collection of sample codes in Keras Github repository](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/tree/master/examples).

[This](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/imdb_lstm.py) is a simple script showing how to train LSTMs. You should be able to run this script as is. To answer why you are getting that specific error `undefined name 'SimpleRNN'`, it seems you forgot to import `SimpleRNN`. Try following the script/link I shared and let me know if it works for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply first you need to import necessary libraries. First of all preprocess your data, then build a model, train your dataset finally you can do prediction part